# How to implement python class attribute containing methods?

Tags: python, inheritance, mixins

I have a class Animal, and I want it to have an attribute which allows access to a specific set of functions.

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

rex = Animal()
rex.actions.bark()
rex.actions.say_age()
```

I tried creating an Actions class and using it as a mixin with multiple inheritance, but that just allows me to do this:

```
rex.say_age()
```

This is not what I want.

I also tried creating an Actions class full of static methods and using them, but this forces me to pass Animal's attributes to the methods.

I know pandas implements this (Series.str is an example), but it looks like it requires a lot of proprietary overhead

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: You are looking for *composition* no inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Just make another class that takes the `Animal` in the constructor.

```
class AnimalActions(object):
  def __init__(self, animal):
    self.animal = animal

class Animal(object):
  def __init__(self, age):
    self.age = age
    self.actions = AnimalActions(self)
```

Comment: Isn't it problematic having a class contain an instance of a second class which contains an instance of the first class? It seems to create an infinitely nesting attribute

Comment: As long as you don't have any `__del__()` (destructor) methods, it's fine. It's a reference cycle, but the Python GC can handle that as long as there are no destructor methods. If there are any destructors on any objects in the cycle, it ends up in `gc.garbage` (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/gc.html#gc.garbage)

Comment: Also it's not "contain", it's only "reference". For each `Animal` object, there will be exactly one `AnimalAction`. Think of it as pointers to each other, rather than them being members / contained data.